# Probability $X_n=k$ for a Markov Chain over the integers

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process, discrete-time

Let $\{X_n\}$ be a Markov chain with state space $\mathcal{S}=\mathbb{Z}$, and $X_0=0,$ and $p_{0,1}=p_{0,-1}=1/2,$ and $p_{i,i+1}=1$ for all $i \ge 1,$ and $p_{i,i-1}=1$ for all $i\le -1.$ The question has multiple parts, but the where I'm stuck is computing $Pr[X_n=j]$ for each $j \in \mathcal{S}$ and then using this to compute $\mathbb{E}[X_n]$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}.$

So far I determined that the initial probabilities are $$\nu_i = \begin{cases}1 & i=0, \\ 0& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ and so $$\begin{align*}Pr(X_n=j)& = \sum_{i\in\mathcal{S}}p_{ij}^{(n)}\nu_i\\
& = \sum_{i=-1}^{-\infty} p_{ij}^{(n)}\nu_i+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}p_{ij}^{(n)}\nu_i+p_{0,j}^{(n)}\nu_0\\ & = p_{0,j}^{(n)},\,\,\forall j \in \mathcal{S}.\end{align*}$$ From here $$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}[X_n]&= \sum_{j\in\mathcal{S}}jp_{0,j}^{(n)}\\ &=\sum_{j=-1}^{-\infty}jp_{0,j}^{(n)} + \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}jp_{0,j}^{(n)}
\end{align*}$$ I'm not sure how to proceed as there are values of $n,$ say $n=5$ such that $p_{0,3}^{(5)}=0.$ Should I break this up into cases for differing $n$?

Edit: Typo

Comment: Drawing a simple diagram might lead you faster to a correct answer than any amount of formulas or algebra will.

Comment: You say "$p_{i,i+1}=1$ for all $i \le -1$". Is that a typo for "$p_{i,i-1}=1$ for all $i \le -1$"?

Comment: Yes. that was a typo. Fixed it.

Comment: @whuber I drew myself a diagram which is 0 at the center and moving to -1 or 1 with probability 1/2 and then from there we move one step up with probability 1 in both directions off into the sunset. So, $Pr[X_n=j]=0$ if $n\neq j$ otherwise it equal 1/2?

Comment: Close, but not quite.  There are two cases to consider, based on the initial transition.  They give two possible values for $X_n.$

Comment: @whuber are the two cases $i=0$ and $i \neq 0?$

Comment: As I wrote, the two cases are the result of the initial transition.